# rulerformat truncated when filename included

Tags: statusline, options, ruler

Given the limited screen real estate on my device (27x48), I'm trying

```
set laststatus=1
set rulerformat=%25(%<%f%M\ %=%l\|%c%)
```

No matter the minwid prefix, or if I apply it to `%()` or `%f`, or if I add a maxwid or two, or if I move the `%<` around, the ruler gets truncated at about half the screen width (25 including `<`). Actually even less if the `%<` is anywhere but at the beginning of `%()`.

Is there some rule about the maximum ruler size?

Edit: for experimenting, a simpler example would be

```
:set rulerformat=%-25.25(%<010203040506070809101
112131415161718192021222324%)
```

Comment: Mnah, %25< causes an error, and anyway I've tried moving %< around and leaving it out as I mentioned

Comment: BTW, is everything in the example required to reproduce the problem? Can you pare it down any? It's best to provide a minimum viable test case.

Comment: Ok.. though it comes down to experimenting or knowing some obscure bit of information (I don't see anything in the docs)

Comment: Cool. This one could be tricky so every little bit helps. :)